# Remove selection from number picker

Tags: android, textselection, numberpicker

I've got a number picker in my activity. It's possible for the user to do a text selection on the current number. The problem is I'd like to reset the selection when the orientation change to avoid the change of the action bar. As extreme solution I could disable selection but I don't know how. I tried to call clearFocus, I tried to set empty longClikListner, I tried to set setSelected(false) and so on. How can I reset a text selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the solution after a lot of work :) Use a dummy layout element with focus, clear the focus from the number picker and request the focus from your dummy element, but you have to do this in onResume ***and*** onPause.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the field is an EditText:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    text.setSelection(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: As I said it's a number picker not a an EditText

Comment: Sorry, i didn't think it was the field type.